# How do I fix my tables so that they work?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have all the data entered into my table but when I go to run it in SQL, I get this message:

> ERROR at line 1:
>   ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SYSTEM.SYS_C008579) violated - parent key not
>   found

```
create table B_C_MAP (
B_C_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
B_ID    integer references BUSINESS(B_ID),
C_ID    integer references CATEGORY(C_ID)
);

insert into BUSINESS values (201, 'Gainesville', 'Bonefish', 301, 'BF Management');
insert into BUSINESS values (202, 'Manassas', 'Target', 302, 'Target Management');
insert into BUSINESS values (203, 'Centreville', 'Trader Joes', 302, 'TJ Management');
insert into BUSINESS values (204, 'Gainesville,', 303, 'VA Tire and Auto', 'TA Management');
insert into BUSINESS values (205, 'Manassas', 'Okras', 301, 'Okras Management');
insert into BUSINESS values (206, 'Gainesville', 'Giant', 302, 'Giant Management');
insert into BUSINESS values (207, 'Centreville', 'Kemper Carpet', 303, 'KC Management');
insert into BUSINESS values (208, 'Manassas', 'Imperial Auto', 303, 'IA Management');
insert into BUSINESS values (209, 'Gainesville', 'Glory Days Grille', 301, 'GDG Management');
insert into BUSINESS values (210, 'Manassas', 'Cracker Barrel', 301, 'SW Management');

insert into CATEGORY values (301, 'Food');
insert into CATEGORY values (302, 'Retail');
insert into CATEGORY values (303, 'Service');

insert into B_C_MAP values (401, 301,201);
insert into B_C_MAP values (402, 301, 205);
insert into B_C_MAP values (403, 301,209);
insert into B_C_MAP values (404, 301,210);
insert into B_C_MAP values (405, 302,202);
insert into B_C_MAP values (406, 302,203);
insert into B_C_MAP values (407, 302,206);
insert into B_C_MAP values (408,303,204);
insert into B_C_MAP values (409, 303,207);
insert into B_C_MAP values (410, 303,208);
```

Comment: First thing to try is to explicitly list the targeted columns in the `INSERT`s like `INSERT INTO BUSINESS (B_ID, ...) ...`.

Answer (score 2):

Get in the habit of listing the fields on the insert you have values for so that you don't try to enter them in the wrong place, as you did.

```
insert into B_C_MAP(b_c_id, c_id, b_id) values (401, 301,201);
```

or

```
insert into B_C_MAP(b_c_id, b_id, c_id) values (401, 201, 301);
```

Comment: Yes, this is the best practice. +1

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation:** It looks like you flipped your value for Business and Category in your B_C_MAP insert statements.

**References:** http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_02291_integrity_constraint_string_string_violated_parent_key_not_found.htm

**Example:**

```
B_ID = 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210
C_ID = 301, 302, 303

insert into B_C_MAP values (B_C_ID, B_ID, C_ID);
insert into B_C_MAP values (401, 201, 301);
```

**Fixed Insert Statements:**

```
insert into B_C_MAP (B_C_ID, B_ID, C_ID) values (401, 201, 301);
insert into B_C_MAP (B_C_ID, B_ID, C_ID) values (402, 205, 301);
insert into B_C_MAP (B_C_ID, B_ID, C_ID) values (403, 209, 301);
insert into B_C_MAP (B_C_ID, B_ID, C_ID) values (404, 210, 301);
insert into B_C_MAP (B_C_ID, B_ID, C_ID) values (405, 202, 302);
insert into B_C_MAP (B_C_ID, B_ID, C_ID) values (406, 203, 302);
insert into B_C_MAP (B_C_ID, B_ID, C_ID) values (407, 206, 302);
insert into B_C_MAP (B_C_ID, B_ID, C_ID) values (408, 204, 303);
insert into B_C_MAP (B_C_ID, B_ID, C_ID) values (409, 207, 303);
insert into B_C_MAP (B_C_ID, B_ID, C_ID) values (410, 208, 303);
```

Comment: Swaping the values does the trick. However, is a poor and unsafe practice in the long term. + 1 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> insert into B_C_MAP (B_C_ID, C_ID, B_ID) values (401, 301,201);

You are writing the values swaped. There's no `BUSINESS` with primary key value of `301`. That's why Oracle refuses to insert the row.

**Solution #1 (preferred & safe)**:

```
insert into B_C_MAP (B_C_ID, C_ID, B_ID) values (401, 301, 201);
```

**Solution #2 (lazy & unsafe)**:

```
insert into B_C_MAP values (401, 201, 301);
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see structure of category and business tables, but seems that category inserts have to be executed before business ones